# Update form with two file fields

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, sql-update, crud

I cannot get my two file upload fields working with my update form. I'm able to get create_form to upload the files to my server and input info into the SQL database, but I can't get the edit to take without receiving an error. Files don't upload and info doesn't update in SQL. Please help!

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/session.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/db_connection.php");?>
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION["login_user"] != true) {
    echo("Access denied!");
    exit();
}
?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/functions.php");?>
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/validation_functions.php");?>
<?php find_selected_event_page(); ?>
<?php
  if (!$current_event) {
    // page ID was missing or invalid or 
    // page couldn't be found in database
    redirect_to("manage_content.php");
  }
?>
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Process the form

    // validations
    $required_fields = array("visible");
    validate_presences($required_fields);   


    if (empty($errors)) {

    // Perform Update
        $id = $current_event["id"];
        $visible = mysql_prep($_POST["visible"]);
        $homepage = mysql_prep($_POST["homepage"]);
        $fa_id = mysql_prep($_POST["fa_id"]);
        $title = mysql_prep($_POST["title"]);
        $caption = mysql_prep($_POST["caption"]);
        $url = mysql_prep($_POST["url"]);
        $month = mysql_prep($_POST["month"]);
        $date = mysql_prep($_POST["date"]);
        $year = mysql_prep($_POST["year"]);
        $summary = mysql_prep($_POST["summary"]);
        $full_text = mysql_prep($_POST["full_text"]);
         $image = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['image']['name'];
            $image_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
            $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
            $image_folder="images/";
            $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
            $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
            $file_folder="files/";

$final_image=str_replace(' ','-',$new_image_name);
$final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

   if($_FILES)  {        

unlink("images/".$current_event['image']);
move_uploaded_file($image_loc,$image_folder.$final_image); 

unlink("files/".$current_event['file']);
move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$file_folder.$final_file); }

        else
  {
   // if no image selected the old image remain as it is.
   $final_image = $current_event['image']; // old image from database
   $fine_file = $current_event['file']; // old image from database

  } 


        $query  = "UPDATE `events` SET ";
        $query .= "`visible` = '{$visible}', ";
        $query .= "`homepage` = '{$homepage}', ";
        $query .= "`fa_id` = '{$fa_id}', ";
        $query .= "`title` = '{$title}', ";
        $query .= "`caption` = '{$caption}', ";
        $query .= "`url` = '{$url}', ";
        $query .= "`month` = '{$month}', ";
        $query .= "`date` = '{$date}', ";
        $query .= "`year` = '{$year}', ";
        $query .= "`summary` = '{$summary}', ";
        $query .= "`full_text` = '{$full_text}', ";
        $query .= "`image` = '{$final_image}', ";
        $query .= "`image_type` = '{$image_type}', ";
        $query .= "`image_size` = '{$image_new_size}' ";
        $query .= "`file` = '{$final_file}', ";
        $query .= "`file_type` = '{$file_type}', ";
        $query .= "`file_size` = '{$file_new_size}' ";
        $query .= "WHERE `events`.`id` = {$id} ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($connection)) {

            // Success
            echo "<pre>".$query."</pre>";

            $_SESSION["message"] = "Item updated.";
            redirect_to("manage_content.php");
        } else {
            // Failure
            //$_SESSION["message"] = "Item creation failed.";
        //redirect_to("new_news.php");
        echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $result->error;

        }

    }
} else {        
    // This is probably a GET request

} // end: if (isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
```

The error I get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'file = '', file_type = '', file_size = '' WHERE events.id = 1 LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

update

```
 $query .= "`image_size` = '{$image_new_size}' ";
```

to

```
 $query .= "`image_size` = '{$image_new_size}' ,";
```

so your final query

```
$query  = "UPDATE `events` SET ";
        $query .= "`visible` = '{$visible}', ";
        $query .= "`homepage` = '{$homepage}', ";
        $query .= "`fa_id` = '{$fa_id}', ";
        $query .= "`title` = '{$title}', ";
        $query .= "`caption` = '{$caption}', ";
        $query .= "`url` = '{$url}', ";
        $query .= "`month` = '{$month}', ";
        $query .= "`date` = '{$date}', ";
        $query .= "`year` = '{$year}', ";
        $query .= "`summary` = '{$summary}', ";
        $query .= "`full_text` = '{$full_text}', ";
        $query .= "`image` = '{$final_image}', ";
        $query .= "`image_type` = '{$image_type}', ";
        $query .= "`image_size` = '{$image_new_size}', ";
        $query .= "`file` = '{$final_file}', ";
        $query .= "`file_type` = '{$file_type}', ";
        $query .= "`file_size` = '{$file_new_size}' ";
        $query .= "WHERE `events`.`id` = {$id} ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Thank you-I can now make edits to the text fields! However, this still will not delete my old files from the server and upload the new ones. Neither is happening... :(

Comment: Ok print_r($current_event); then check your data get ok

Comment: It seems to be getting everything up until image type

Comment: Although the strange thing now is there is no mySQL error reporting - it's empty